# Synchronous ajax request with a timeout?

Tags: javascript, ajax, comet

I wrote a web forum that also works as a synchronous chat client (posts appear immediately). This works in the usual way by using a single long-polling ajax request (sometimes called "comet").

When the user closes a tab with one of these "chat rooms" loaded in it, I need to tell the server that this user is leaving the room so that they are removed from the "users viewing" list as well as make sure that new posts that arrive after they have left are marked unread.

Right now I am doing this using a synchronous ajax (third parameter to open() is false) request to the server in a window.onbeforeunload handler. It usually returns in < 2 seconds, so little to no impact on usability.

Now for the problem. Say this user already has 5+ tabs open with chat rooms hosted on this same domain. Then they close one. The browser's max simultaneous http requests per domain value kicks in and makes the "I am leaving" synchronous ajax request wait for one of the other requests to complete, but those may never complete because they are comet ("long-polling" or whatever). So now I've effectively locked open the tab they tried to close.

Obvious solution if javascript weren't single-threaded would be a short timeout on the synchronous ajax request.

Comment: Why not just do it asynchronously and then wait a little bit to make sure its been sent and then let the tab close? If the operation fails, what are you going to do? Its sort of a best attempt thing then.

Comment: Lee Meador: OK, but how do you recommend I "wait"? I think there aren't any "sleep()"-like functions in JS for a good reason ...

Comment: You are right. I don't know the answer to that. I'd probably try some different things to see if I could get the close to wait a quarter second or so.

Comment: There is another whole way to do this. Sort of a "dead man switch". The web page has a repeating timed event at, say, 15 seconds. Every 15 seconds you send a small message to the server that indicates, "I'm alive." The server watches for these and if too long goes by without a message, for any particular user, it logs that user out--so to speak.